# rxjs Observable publishReplay new data

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to cache User data with rxjs and this works like a charm with

```
protected users$ = Observable.defer(() => this.getUsersUncached())
    .publishReplay(1, 5000)
    .refCount()
    .take(1);

public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    this.users$.shareReplay()
    return this.users$;
}

public getUsersUncached(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.api.get('/user')
        .map((response) => response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

if i call getUsers i get cached userData for 5 seconds, and if i call getUsersUncached i get my data uncached from the api

What would be super neat if the call to getUserUncached would also reset the timer of the cache and update it's content. What i'm asking is there an clean method for this or should i just build my own with a timer & a BehaviorSubject?